# frame-variables relate to frame-values

Tags: scheme, sicp

Section [4.1.3  Evaluator Data Structures of SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%_sec_4.1.3)

Which illustrate make-frame

> Each frame of an environment is represented as a pair of lists: a list
>   of the variables bound in that frame and a list of the associated
>   values.

```
(define (make-frame variables values)
  (cons variables values));;
(define (frame-variables frame) (car frame))
(define (frame-values frame) (cdr frame))
(define (add-binding-to-frame! var val frame)
  (set-car! frame (cons var (car frame)))
  (set-cdr! frame (cons val (cdr frame))))
```

So frame-variables and frame-values are stored, but in a distinguished way, they are not related to each other as in a hashmap structure.

How frame-variables and associated values connected with one another?

Answer (score 0):

if x = 2 and y = 7 and z = 'foo then if frame-variables was the list (x z y), then frame-values would be the list (2 foo 7)